# ImportError: No module named 'nltk.corpus'; 'nltk' is not a package pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, nltk

in the idle python 3.5.1

```
>>>from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
>>>no error
```

but in the pycharm it is throwing error

**ImportError: No module named 'nltk.corpus'; 'nltk' is not a package**

previously same thing was working fine , but then I did **invaidate caches/restrart** for no good reason and then its throwing this error.
I have checked project interpreter setting its 3.5.1 there also.
Any help is appreciable.

Comment: have you looked at the advice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570182/error-importing-nltk-on-pycharm)?

Comment: @patrick I did silly mistake , I created a  new file named as nltk.py in the same project , where I needed the nltk(the toolkit) , just saw it and after removal it started working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install 'nltk' package for Pycharm. Go to Settings>Project_Name>Project Interpreter. Click on the '+' button and search for 'nltk' and install it. It'd work after that.

Comment: I did silly mistake , I created a new file named as nltk.py in the same project , where I needed the nltk(the toolkit) , just saw it and after removal it started working fine :)